# Can I use another company's code to rent a car, and use my credit card insurance?

Tags: car-rentals

I plan to rent a car using my Friend's employee code. My credit card covers CDW( Collision Damage Waiver) and I think that's what the company covers too. So will my credit card cover the insurance just in case anything happens? Will it be a problem if I use my friend's code?

Comment: What are the rules for your friend's code? Is it allowed for other people to use it?

Comment: By providing his code for use by others, your friend is likely violating the terms of his employment. Too, the rental agency may enter the discount code in the computer, see that the code "owner" is not the renter, and refuse to apply the code, or just refuse the rental. This is not likely to end well.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica a lot of the corporate codes are floating around on the Internet, so you could find them without having a friend working there

Comment: @JonathanReez Well then it might work. Never tried it myself.

Comment: I recently made a car reservation using my employer's contract number with one of the large US car rental agencies.  In the reservation confirmation from the rental car company, it says they may request proof of employment by that employer to honor the contract terms and rate.  I will have proof of employment when I pick up my rental vehicle in case they ask for it, but if I were you, I wouldn't risk it.  Too many things could go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the insurance, it is *likely* that no-one will care. However, my experience with company discount codes is that rental locations *may* ask for employee card or any other evidence of you actually being entitled to use the discount. I once had to allow the rental desk email me at my work email address to confirm.

If something *does* happen and you actually need that insurance - then you'll be in a lot of trouble. Your credit card will refuse to cover since your rental agreement would show CDW being included. But the rental company at that point will most definitely check if you were in fact entitled to use the discount, and will refuse to honor the contract CDW since you were not entitled to use the discount. As mentioned, your friend will get in trouble as well for sharing the code, and the company may get in trouble with the rental company for allowing this to happen.

Comment: You can refuse CDW coverage from the company even if your corporate code includes it, at least with Avis.

Comment: @JonathanReez actually my company has a contract with Avis, and if I use the discount code the CDW is added automatically and cannot be removed. Or so I've been told.

Comment: Interesting... I guess there's different contracts depending on the company.

Comment: There seem to be lots of different contracts. My company's corporate codes (both Avis and Hertz) resulted in CDW being automatically refused; the company instead provided a corporate credit card to use for insurance for business travel. I had no trouble using the code (for the discount) and my own card for personal travel.